# Running Artisan commands in Production Environment - Laravel 4.*

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, shared-hosting

Am stuck on how to run artisan commands in production environment. Am using Hostgator (shared Hosting) as my hosting company. Am trying to run commands via ftp client in my win8 machine. All commands do not work. It gives "invalid command" error.

Can anyone help on this? ! Thanks. Below is an example command that i tried to run.

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Try using exec(), but it might be your user could need higher rights in order for them to succeed

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..can you elaborate more on how to use exec() command together with an artisan command. Is it like exec( php atrisan ... ) or...

Answer (score 5):

You can't use FTP to run artisan (or more precisely php). For that you'd need SSH access.

I'm also in a shared hosting environment where I don't have access and I decided to use [WebArtisan](https://github.com/JN-Jones/web-artisan). This creates a page from where you can run artisan commands.

But you should be careful as this can be quite dangerous. 
You should use an 'auth' filter to protect the console from being accessed by anyone else, or at least use a secure route and password.

Only downside is you won't be able to use composer in this "web console" (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas said, you can't use FTP to run php commands. I also use Hostgator and can simply SSH into my shared server and run artisan commands. Since you're using Windows (I'm on Linux) it's a bit trickier, you'll need to download an application such as WinSCP or PuTTY.

Here is an article Hostgator has provided to get you started using SSH:

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/how-do-i-get-and-use-ssh-access